# Angular refreshing page with a button

Tags: angular, typescript

What I want to do is have a button that does the same thing as the refresh button in chrome does.  I have tried location.reload(), and it doesn't seem to really do anything.  Is there any way to do this?

```
exit() {
    location.reload();
  }

 <button [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" (click)="exit()">Exit</button>
```

Comment: Well the function is not even called, or is it a typo? should be `(click)="exit()"`

Comment: Something I should have caught, however the "()" is unnecessary, as could still run stuff from the exit() method even with typo.

Comment: Well the function isn't called if you mark it as `exit`, so I don't know what you expect to happen. The routerLink won't reload if you are on dashboard component already.

Comment: I solved it now, and sorry if it wasn't clear but this was from a different component, a detail screen.  The exit button and method where on my detail component.

Comment: Yeah I assumed that you were on the dashboard component, since you wanted to reload. But glad to hear that it got solved! :)

Comment: refreshing the entire page is an anti-pattern in angular; you probably just need to reset the state of your objects without an actual browser refresh

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this: `window.location.reload();`

Comment: That didn't seem to work, I'm not sure if it matters, but this button also goes paths to my dashboard.

Comment: Can you try changing the click handler declaration to `(click)="exit()"`

Comment: So I tried doing this and it didn't work (the original answer) and I just tried again, with exact same line and it worked.  I didn't change anything else so im not sure why it worked suddenly.

Answer (score 2):

This will reload to default route page

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-refresh-banner-notification',
  templateUrl: './refresh-banner-notification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./refresh-banner-notification.component.scss']
})
export class RefreshBannerNotificationComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document
  ) {}

  refreshPage() {
    this._document.defaultView.location.reload();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the  `[routerLink]="['/dashboard']"` from the button.

```
exit() {
   window.location.reload();
}

 <button (click)="exit()">Exit</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using

HTML:

```
<button (click)="reload()">click me</button>
```

TS:

```
reload(){
  // any other execution
  this.ngOnInit()
}
```